# Centralizer of a transposition in permutation group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $\pi$ be a transposition in permutation group $S_n$ that $n>1$. Is the centralizer of $\pi$ on $S_n$ i.e $C_{S_n}(\pi)$ isomorphic with $\mathbb Z_2\times S_{n-2}$ or $\mathbb Z_2\times S_{n-1}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume for convenience that $\pi$ is the permutation $(1 \ 2)$.  Show that if $\sigma \in S_n$ satisfies $\sigma(1) \notin \{1, 2\}$ or $\sigma(2) \notin \{1, 2\}$ then $\sigma$ does not commute with $\pi$.

Comment: @ Jim please explain more

Comment: A permutation $\sigma$ is in the centralizer of $(1 \ 2)$ if and only if $\sigma(1), \sigma(2) \in \{1, 2\}$.